# Pebble shader in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

I need to make some pebbles for my scene. How do I get the realistic looking pebble shader in Cycles? This is what I am going for:

[image]

And I have got this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

It is mostly procedural, I did use an image texture for the grooves but you could take that out and use a voroni texture (I just liked the way the texture looked).

If you are trying to make a ground plane with thousands of pebbles I would NOT go this route. I would use a pebble texture and use displacement. However if you are going for a close up pebble shot this shader should work well.

[image]
[image]

The trick is to build up the layers of detail.

The main left box is the main rock color, It is just broken up with a noise texture and 3 different colors. Use the color ramp to clamp the pattern.

*Notice I put a hue/saturation node (highlighted) I did this to quickly change the color of different rocks (or you could just change the 3 original colors).

The middle and front box are just for the scratches and grooves in the rock. The most important part here is to use the texture as a bump with a different color and material for the chipped grooves.

- I added in a texture and mapping node to just change the look of the textures across the different rocks (So they don't all look the same).

Comment: you are too good bro. thanks. Can you help me build a rock texture as well? i am just trying to learn procedural shading? what do you think is the best way to learn it or is there any concept i need to grasp first?

Comment: Honestly its just practice. It seems intimidating at first but you really use the same nodes over and over again so you quickly learn. You can post another question for a certain rock texture here is a salt rock https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95399/how-to-make-himalayan-rock-salt-chunks-in-blender This is kinda advanced but I learned so much recreating it. https://www.artstation.com/artwork/KdDxx